# What options do i have to make this code thread safe?

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety

I have this segment of code , a lot of things skipped for brevity but the scene is this one:

```
 public class Billing
    {
        private List<PrecalculateValue> Values = new List<PrecalculateValue>();

        public int GetValue(DateTime date)
        {
            var preCalculated = Values.SingleOrDefault(g => g.date == date).value;
            //if exist in Values, return it
            if(preCalculated != null)
            {
               return preCalculated;
            }

            // if it does not exist calculate it and store it in Values
            int value = GetValueFor(date);
            Values.Add(new PrecalculateValue{date = date, value = value});

            return value;
        }

        private object GetValueFor(DateTime date)
        {
            //some logic here
        }
    }
```

I have a `List<PrecalculateValue> Values` where i store all the values i already calculated for later use, i do these mainly because i don't want to recalculate things twice for the same client, each calculation involve a lot of operations and take between 500 and 1000 ms, and there is a big chance of reuse that value, because of some recursion involved in the hole billing class.

All of these work perfectly until i made a test where i hit two simultaneous calculations  for two different clients, and the line `Values.Single(g => g.date == date).value` returned an exception because it found more than one result in the collection.
So i checked the list and it stored values of both clients in the same list. What can i do to avoid this little problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first of all, this line:

```
return Values.Single(g => g.date == date).value;
```

makes it so that the subsequent lines will never be called. I'm guessing you've paraphrased your code a little bit here?

If you want to synchronize writes to your `Values` list, the most straightforward way would be to `lock` on a common object everywhere in the code that you're modifying the list:

```
int value = GetValueFor(date);

lock (dedicatedLockObject) {
    Values.Add(new PrecalculateValue{date = date, value = value});
}

return value;
```

But here's something else worth noting: since it looks like you want to have one `PrecalculateValue` per `DateTime`, a more appropriate data structure would probably be a `Dictionary<DateTime, PrecalculateValue>` -- it will provide lightning-fast, O(1) lookup based on your `DateTime` key, as compared to a `List<PrecalculateValue>` which would have to iterate to find what you're looking for.

With this change in place, your code might look something like this:

```
public class Billing
{
    private Dictionary<DateTime, PrecalculateValue> Values = 
        new Dictionary<DateTime, PrecalculateValue>();

    private readonly commonLockObject = new object();

    public int GetValue(DateTime date)
    {
        PrecalculateValue cachedCalculation;

        // Note: for true thread safety, you need to lock reads as well as
        // writes, to ensure that a write happening concurrently with a read
        // does not corrupt state.
        lock (commonLockObject) {
            if (Values.TryGetValue(date, out cachedCalculation))
                return cachedCalculation.value;
        }

        int value = GetValueFor(date);

        // Here we need to check if the key exists again, just in case another
        // thread added an item since we last checked.
        // Also be sure to lock ANYWHERE ELSE you're manipulating
        // or reading from the collection.
        lock (commonLockObject) {
            if (!Values.ContainsKey(date))
                Values[date] = new PrecalculateValue{date = date, value = value};
        }

        return value;
    }

    private object GetValueFor(DateTime date)
    {
        //some logic here
    }
}
```

And one last piece of advice: unless it's critical that no more than one of a particular value exist in your collection, the `Single` method is overkill. If you'd rather just get the first value and disregard potential duplicates, `First` is both safer (as in, less chance of an exception) and faster (because it doesn't have to iterate over the entire collection).

Comment: +1 for using a dictionary keyed on the DateTime. Also if you are using .NET 4 there is a new ConcurrentDictionary that will handle the locking for you when adding new objects.

Comment: hehe ,yep those commented if´s are actually part of the logic =), sry about that. I´ll give it a try later

Comment: @Dan: Why use a lock object and not simply lock the Values object?

Comment: im not using .NET 4, but it sounds really nice to handle this situations.

Comment: You are locking only The Add to the List.But I think you should lock the "search list" part also.Otherwise another thread might insert same record while you are searching

Comment: @josephj1989: I guess you're referring to the short code snippet at the top of my answer? I was just providing an excerpt there. You can see in the longer chunk of code I posted I did advise locking the entire operation (key lookup as well as insertion).

Comment: @Paul Creasey: I don't have an exceptional answer to that question; all I can say is, in my experience, using a dedicated object to serve as the lock ends up being a wise move. Of course it doesn't really matter what object you lock on as long as it's appropriately narrow in scope (don't want to lock on some global object that has no relation to what you're doing for example) and as long as it's the same object everywhere you're trying to synchronize your code. The one thing I've noticed is that sometimes developers get into this habit of locking on the collection object itself... (cont.)

Comment: @Paul Creasey: ...and eventually they start to think that simply by locking on the object they're magically ensuring the atomicity of whatever particular block of code they're writing. And then suddenly they act surpised when a threading-related error occurs right in the middle of that code. In other words, locking on a separate object makes it easier (for me) to remember that what you're doing is not making a piece of code inherently thread-safe, but rather synchronizing it with code that locks on the same object. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Could use something like this

```
public int GetValue(DateTime date)
{

    var result = Values.Single(g => g.date == date) ?? GetValueFor(date);

    lock (Values)
    {
        if (!Values.Contains(result)) Values.Add(result);
    }
    return result.value;
}

private PrecalculateValue GetValueFor(DateTime date)
{
    //logic
    return new PrecalculateValue() ;
}
```

Would advise using a dictionary though for a list of key value pairs.